# fatal error: src/include/SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, include-path

The part where it says

```cpp
#include <src/include/SDL2/SDL.h>
```

is not working.
My compile error is

```
fatal error: src/include/SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

Here my entire code

```cpp
#include <src/include/SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1280 
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 720

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        printf("Error: SDL failed to initialize\nSDL Error: '%s'\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SLD test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0);
    if(!window){
        printf("Error: Failed to open window\nSDL Error: '%s'\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if(!renderer){
        printf("Error: Failed to create renderer\nSDL Error: '%s'\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    bool running = true;
    while(running){
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My Makefile file

```
all:
    g++ -I scr/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Pls help

Comment: The makefile mis-spells "src".  It would then, probably, be `#include "SDL2/sdl2.h"`

Answer (score 1):

If your command line has src/include, then the includes will be relative to that directory.  BTW you posted scr/include.

So either -I . or -I src/include and #include "SDL2/SDL2.h"